# scroll down or open link

Tags: javascript, html, django, jinja2

with hard work I've  achieved to make A scroll down to a specefic `div` when clicking on a specific menu item, the issue that I have is in another menu item `contact` that opens another page `contact.html`. it does't work when using `href="{% url 'contact' %}"`

```
<div class="main-menu mean-menu float-right">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#hero-area">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#feature-area">about<i class="icofont"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#gallery-area">gallery<i class="icofont"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#instructor-area">services<i class="icofont"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'blog' %}">blog<i class="icofont"></i></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'blog' %}">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog-details.html">Blog Details</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'contact' %}">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**.JS CODE**

```
$('.main-menu ul li a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $('html, body').animate(
    {
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top,
    },
    500,
    'linear'
  )
})
var menuLi = $('.main-menu ul li');
menuLi.on('click', function(){
    var currLink = $(this);
    if( menuLi.hasClass('active') ){
        menuLi.removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

**View**

```
def contact(request):
return render(request, 'sc_drive/contact.html')
```

**URL**

```
path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so simple, removed this piece of code and it works

```
e.preventDefault()
```